# How to perform logical AND between two query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database is SQL Server 2017.

How to perform logical AND operation between two selects?

Here's the problem: I need to check if there are no executions for a particular process within a time range **(count <=0)** AND if there are messages in the queue **(count >0)**. If the previous statement is true, then return 1. Any other combination returns 0

To check number of executions

```
select count(*) as 'workflow_count' 
from MY_TABLE
where 1=1
  and [PROCESS] = 'A'
  and [DATE] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE())
```

To check number of messages

```
select SUM(total) as 'message_count'
from
    (select count(*) total 
     from [dbo].[QUEUE1]
     union all
     select count(*) total 
     from [dbo].[QUEUE2]) s
```

Comment: Get  rid of those `with (nolock)` hints. They probably aren't accomplishing what you've been led to believe.

Comment: Why do you union all QUEUE1 with QUEUE1?

Comment: Single quotes (`'`) are the literal string too; it's a really bad habit to use them for aliases. Some methods of using them are deprecated, and their use is often confusing for others (especially new users). If you *need* to delimit identify your object names, use brackets (`[]`) or double quotes (`"`)

Comment: @jarlh Application uses two queues for processing, the message can be on either

Comment: @BrunoCampiol The point about the UNION in your query is that you are UNION-ing QUEUE1 with itself..  Since it is an UNION ALL it will return two identical counts.  Did you mean to make one of the branches QUEUE2?

Comment: @RBarryYoung you are right, my mistake, they are different queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` and [`not`] `exists` (subquery)

```
select 
   case when (not exists (
      select 1 
      from  TABLE 
      where 1=1
          and [PROCESS] = 'A'
          and [DATE] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -5, GETDATE()))

     ) and exists (
       select 1
       from [dbo].[QUEUE1]
     )
   then 1 else 0 end x;
```

Comment: This works well! Thanks